# Conditional routing for nested resource in Rails controller #edit action, depending on where request came from

Tags: ruby-on-rails, redirect, controller, routes

I have a Foo resource that `has_many` Bars. I'm using nested resources for a limited number of actions, but otherwise prefer to keep my routing for bars shallow. There are two ways to navigate to the edit view for the Bar object - either from the nested path that includes `foo`, or from the shallower `bar` path that isn't nested inside `foo`. For example, a user might click the edit button from the page at `/foos/[:foo_id]/bar/[:bar_id]`; or from `/bars/[:bar_id]`.

In the first case, I want the controller to redirect the user back to the parent foo page: `/foos/[:foo_id]` after the record is updated. In the second case, I want it to redirect to the index view for `bars`: `/bars`. I believe I need some sort of conditional in the `#edit` action in the `bars` controller that will tell Rails where to go after `#update` executes.

```
# config/routes.rb
resources :foos do
  resources :bars, only: [:new, :edit]
end

resources :bars

# bin/rake routes:
foo_bars     POST   /foos/:foo_id/bars(.:format)          bars#create
new_foo_bar  GET    /foos/:foo_id/bars/new(.:format)      bars#new
edit_foo_bar GET    /foos/:foo_id/bars/:id/edit(.:format) bars#edit
        bars GET    /bars(.:format)                       bars#index
             POST   /bars(.:format)                       bars#create
     new_bar GET    /bars/new(.:format)                   bars#new
    edit_bar GET    /bars/:id/edit(.:format)              bars#edit
         bar GET    /bars/:id(.:format)                   bars#show
             PATCH  /bars/:id(.:format)                   bars#update
             PUT    /bars/:id(.:format)                   bars#update
             DELETE /bars/:id(.:format)                   bars#destroy
```

The controller for `bars`:

```
# app/controllers/bar_controller.rb
def edit
  @bar = bar.find(params[:id])
  @foo = @bar.foo
end

def update
  @bar = bar.find(params[:id])
  @foo = @bar.foo

  respond_to do |format|
    if @bar.update_attributes(bar_params)
      format.html { redirect_to @foo, notice: "bar successfully updated" }
    else
      format.html { render action: "edit" }
    end
  end
end
```

I'm trying to change the `redirect_to @foo` line in the `#update` action so there is conditional logic that switches out `@foo` for `@bars` depending on where the `#edit` action was initiated. I've tried something like the following to test whether `params[:foo]` is present when the `#edit` action is called, setting an instance variable for the redirect.

```
def edit
  if params[:foo]
    @redirect_page = @foo
  else
    @redirect_page = @bars
  end
  @bar = bar.find(params[:id])
  @foo = @bar.foo
end

def update
  # code omitted...
      format.html { redirect_to @redirect_page, notice: "bar successfully updated" }
  # code omitted...
end
```

This doesn't work. Rails states `cannot redirect to nil!`. I've also tried something using a test based on `URI(request.referer).path` in the `#edit` action, without success.

I'm still not entirely clear how the Rails magic happens in the controller. I believe the `#edit` action is the proper place to define the conditional for the redirect (or through a method called in the `#edit` action), as that's where the controller will "see" the incoming request and know where it came from. But I can't quite figure out to capture that information, and pass it along to `#update`. Appreciate any guidance.

Comment: you are defining `@redirect_page` on edit action. You need to do it on update action. On edit form you can set de `foo_id` as a hidden field.

Comment: but I need to capture where the request is coming from when `#edit` is invoked. If I put the logic in the `#update` action I can't see the original request. E.g. in the web-console on the edit form, `URI(request.referer).path` returns `/foos/[:foo_id]`. After submit (with `console` invoked in the `#update` action), it returns `/bars/[:bar_id]/edit`. This doesn't tell me where `#edit` was invoked. BTW I realize that `#edit` is exposed for the nested resource in foo; however using a shared view to display the `bars#index` and bars on the `foo#show` page. Was trying to avoid additional view logic

Answer (score 2):

In your edit forms, add a `hidden_field_tag`:

```
<%= hidden_field_tag "route", request.env['PATH_INFO'] %>
```

Then in your controller, you can have an `if` statement and use a `redirect_to` based on what the `params[:route]` is.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. The params[:route] method using `request.env['PATH_INFO]` wasn't working for me, because the 'PATH_INFO' variable in the form was providing the path handed off to the `bars#update` action, instead of the path where the `bars#edit` action was initiated.

After clicking "Edit" from the parent foo page at `/foos/[:id]` the params hash is:

```
>>  params
=> {"controller"=>"bars", "action"=>"edit", "foo_id"=>"3786", "id"=>"16"}
```

There is no value for `params[:route]` when the form is first accessed - the hidden field is only added to the params hash after clicking "Update" in the edit form:

```
>>  params[:route]
=> "/foos/3786/bars/16/edit"
```

This could work, but would require building logic to parse the route in order to redirect to `/foos/[:foo_id]`

It turned out to be simpler to use the Rails `flash` method to store the path for redirecting back to the source page. I did this by calling a custom method `set_redirect_path` in the BarsController, and calling it in `bars#edit`. This sets a value for the source in the flash, which is available in `bars#update`. Maybe there's a better/more conventional way to achieve this, but this seems to be a clean and simple way to do what I want.

```
# app/controllers/bars_controller.rb
def edit
  set_redirect_path
  @bar = bar.find(params[:id])
  @foo = @bar.foo
end

def update
  @bar = bar.find(params[:id])
  @foo = @bar.foo

  respond_to do |format|
    if @bar.update_attributes(bar_params)
      format.html { redirect_to flash[:source], notice: "bar successfully updated" }
      format.xml { head :ok }
    else
      format.html { render action: "edit" }
      format.xml { render xml: @bar.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
    end
  end
end

private
  def set_redirect_path
    flash[:source] = URI(request.referer).path
  end
```

One advantage of this approach is I can now get rid of conditional logic in the shared partial `app/views/bars/_list.html.haml` that was required to determine whether clicking the "Edit" button should route to `edit_foo_bar_path` or to `edit_bar_path` (i.e. the former is chosen if `@foo` exists). Consequently, I can delete `:edit` for the nested resource `:bars`. Since the flash captures the incoming source of the request and stores it for reference in the `#update` action, all edit requests can use the same `edit_bar_path`, regardless of where they originate from. After update Rails redirects the user to the point where they initiated the `#edit` action.